# Submit_tag button won't obey CSS width

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following form:

```
<%= form_tag users_path, :method => :get do %>
  <%= #... %>
  <%= submit_tag("", class:"submit-button") %>
<% end %>
```

I can style the submit_tag button any way I want using CSS3, except for its width. It remains at 16px width no matter what I do. Anyone know why this might be, or how I can debug it?

**css**

```
@import "bootstrap";

.submit-button {width:100px;height:100px;}
```

Comment: Add `display: inline-block;` which will respect the `width` and `height` attributes.  Which browser are you using?  There should be DOM inspector built into the browser.  Give that a try.  E.g. `Ctrl+Shift+I` in Chrome to bring the Developers Tools.

Comment: Added `display: inline-block;`, but it still won't budge from 16px width. I can style the height, though. What can I do inside the inspector to debug it?

Comment: Try `width: 100px !important;` for debugging purpose and to see if it is overriding or not.

Comment: Ah, now it works! So where was it being overridden? I know I didn't set any other css.

Comment: Inspect with firebug or chrome inspector, and see which old style is overriding your new style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with:

```
width: 100px !important;
```

But it's not recommended. I am sure some other css is overriding your current css style. So inspect it and put your button style after that style.